# remove horizontal scroll bar at the bottom in magento site

Tags: magento, scrollbar

please visit this link http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/

in the bottom , you can see "horizontal scroll bar". I want to remove that "scroll bar".

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a lot of issues. The main one starts in this line:

```
<div><p style="position: relative; left: 550px; font-size: 30px; top: 50px; color: blue;"><span style="font-size: xx-large;"><span style="color: #330099;"><strong>Ph: 0800 844 866 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></span> <a style="background-color: orange; color: white; padding: 8px; position: relative; left: 100px; top: 0px; font-size: 22px;" href="http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/contacts/"> Email Us</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;</span></p></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Sadly, there's no real way to fix it without changing all the HTML and only then the CSS. But here is what you need to do:

1) please get rid of inline styles. Give elements a class name so you can manipulate them.

2) give a class to that starting div

3) replace that `p style[...]` with `<div class="your_class">`

4) Now move EVERYTHING inside this div inside div "header-bottom-content". Add it after your logo

5) Now you can play with that div depending on what you want. One possibility could be this:

```
.header-bottom-content{display:block;}
.logo{display:inline-block;}
.your-class{display:inline-block; float:right}
.link-bottom:clear:both; float:none}
```

There are many many ways to do this, the important thing is to fix the HTML and avoid inline styles as much as possible

Comment: please visit this link : http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/  phone number and email is displaying far above than "SEarcH BOx" and "REGISTER AND SIGN IN". 

please help me to bring  Phone number and Email to move little bottom and "email us
to move little left".

thanks in advance.

Comment: you didn't do what I told you, you did something completely different. Don't get me wrong, it's great that you try and I encourage you to try your own path and learn, it's the purpose of this site. But try to do it in a reasonable way by reading some HTML+CSS tutorials first, or please follow instructions.

Comment: no, i really did't had intention to follow other way. I think i misunderstood your solution. i used the above 4 line code provided by you. and i removed the inline css by position:relative; left:top; i used in external style sheet, i added the above 4 lines code in external style sheet, theme.css. please visit this link : http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/ and guide in right path. i am a fresher to this . I want to learn lot from you.

Comment: please visit the link and check : http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/ , this is what i needed . i got the solution from your help and tell me if any mistakes and what corrections i have to do? thanks in advance.

Comment: i am feeling sad that i can't "vote up" your answer as i don't have 15 reputation....

Comment: OK, here you have a fast one since I'm falling asleep. YOU'LL NEED TO MODIFY IT but you'll find more or less the correct nesting of divs and its styling . See it at http://jsfiddle.net/ry0tns8a/

Comment: that's okay, okay, than i will try that link , thanks.